# Thales theorem - using euclidien axioms

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I wonder if it possible to prove the Thales theorem only with Euclidean axioms.
what do you think?

Comment: Euclid's original axioms are flawed (even in his first theorem, Euclid himself has to use assumptions not based on his own axioms). While the idea behind them has been tremendously important to mathematics throughout millennia, to use them directly in this modern age would, in my opinion, not be a good idea.

Comment: There is a proof in Euclid's Elements, if that is what you want.

Comment: Yes,I wold like to see it please

Comment: Here it is: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII31.html

Comment: perfect! Thankyou.